# source address with requests or urllib module

Tags: python-3.x, http.client

Presently I am using http.client module to download files from my apache server. I want to know if there is a way to replace this set of code with requests or urllib module.

```
con = http.client.HTTPConnection(ip,source_address=(s_ip,80))
con.request("GET","/"+file_name)
r1 = con.getresponse()
```

Can I do this above task using requests or urllib module. I want to send multiple requests from multiple source ip .